# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, backend, spring-security

Estoy tratando de crear la funcionalidad iniciar sesión con el siguiente artículo [Spring Boot, Security, and Data MongoDB Authentication Example](https://www.djamware.com/post/5b2f000880aca77b083240b2/spring-boot-security-and-data-mongodb-authentication%20-%20ejemplo) pero estoy teniendo problemas en el servicio `UserDetailsService` de la clase `CustomUserDetailsService`, ya que cuando implemento la dependiencia `UserDetailsService` no me estába aceptando la dependencia, estoy siguiendo el articulo tal cual pero ahora tengo problemas con mi servicio y no se si es por las dependencias o sera el servicio pero no se cual sea el motivo

este es mi `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.trabajoGrado</groupId>
    <artifactId>trabajoGrado</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>trabajoGrado</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cosium.spring.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-entity-graph</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.4.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Me sale el siguiente error

```
contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usuariosService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bCryptPasswordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Este es mi servicio

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package com.trabajoGrado.service;

import com.trabajoGrado.model.Role;
import com.trabajoGrado.model.Usuarios;
import com.trabajoGrado.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.trabajoGrado.repository.UsuariosRepository;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 *
 * @author pipes
 */
@Service
public class UsuariosService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuariosRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public Usuarios findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
    
      public void saveUser(Usuarios user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setEnabled(true);
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Usuarios user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user != null) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
            return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("username not found");
        }
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.forEach((role) -> {
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
        });

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>(roles);
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(Usuarios user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

@Bean
private BCryptPasswordEncoder fulano() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


}
```

este es el error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-29 17:07:38.522 ERROR 10552 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

???->???
|  usuariosService (field private org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder com.trabajoGrado.service.UsuariosService.bCryptPasswordEncoder)
???<-???


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

Comment: el mensaje de error sasle cortado, puedes ponerlo completo y en texto?

Comment: tengo un error en mi servicio dice que Error creating bean with name 'usuariosService' ya agrege el error en texto

Comment: intenta agregar la dependencia spring-security-crypto y en tu configuracion pon un metodo anotado con @Bean que regrese un  `return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();`

Comment: le agrege la dependencia de https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto/6.0.1  y un metodo que retorne return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();  y sigue igual   me sale el error Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-29 11:59:33.618 ERROR 24832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

Comment: eso no es un error en si, solamente dice que puedes correr la aplicación con modo depuración para ver una traza de errores mas detallada el error viene debajo de eso. edita tu pregunta y agrega esa información, estos comentarios casi nadie los lee

Comment: Si hay info adicional a la pregunta, se añade yendo a [edit[ y añádiendo las trazas de error completas, los cambios que has probado,etc. En los comentarios es infumable el código, acá sólo está para pedirte aclaraciones antes de escribirte respuestas

Comment: ya agrege lo que me sale en la pregurtnta